# É possível otimizar meu codigo para uma unica query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, query

Tenho o seguinte problema: estou montando um grafico Highcharts com consultas `php` e acabo tendo um while dentro de outro  pois o resultado da data eu coloco na próxima consulta, tem como retornar em uma unica `query`?

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
$query="SELECT distinct data FROM lista";
$output = sqlsrv($query, $conn);
while($row = sql_srv_fetch_array($output)){
   $query2="SELECT MATERIAL FROM lista WHERE data='".$row['data']."'";
   $output2 = sqlsrv($query2, $conn);
   while($row2 = sql_srv_fetch_array($output2)){
      echo $row['MATERIAL'];  
 }

}
?>
```

Quero como retorno uma query só que retorne a coluna data da forma `[data1,data2,data3,....,dataN]` e coluna material da forma `[material1,material2,material3,...,materialN]`. Como montar esse unico `select`?

Comment: Você não pode simplesmente buscar os materiais com suas respectivas datas?

Answer (score 1):

Teste o seguinte:

Ao final os dois `arrays` estarão com os valores no formato que precisa.

```
<?php 
    include 'config.php';
    $query = "SELECT data, material FROM lista GROUP BY data, material ORDER BY data ASC";
    $output = sqlsrv($query, $conn);
    while($row = sql_srv_fetch_array($output)){
        $datas[] = $row['data'];
        $materiais[] = $row['material'];
        // o seguinte terá um array com todos materiais referentes a xx/xx/xxxx datas
        $array[$row['data']][] = $row['material'];
        // Assim terás 
        //$array['dataX'] = ['material1', 'material2'];
        //$array['dataY'] = ['material3', 'material4'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Não é bem isso.... tem que retornar em uma array os materiais daquela data por exemplo. Datas[20/05,21/05,22/05] e materaiais[material1-material2, material3-material4, material5-material6] onde material 1 e 2 sao da data 20/05, material 3 e 4 da data 21/05 e assim por diante

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se resolve